# Getting time and date when file was copied on Windows XP

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, windows-xp

I have scheduled a batch file on a Windows XP machine to copy a number of text files from a Network Share. The next time this task runs the files are simply overwritten. Batch file goes something like this

```
copy \\networkshare1\*.txt C:\monitoring\files\
copy \\networkshare2\*.txt C:\monitoring\files\
```

I then use Perl to analyse the files. What I would like to know is if there is an easy way, without changing the file name, of recording somewhere what time the file was copied from the network share so that my Perl script knows whether it is working with an old or new version of the file.

Comment: old/new implies a comparison, so you'll have to record the previous state/timestamp/checksum/whatever to determine that...

Answer (score 5):

One way, assuming destination is NTFS:

```
set dest=C:\monitoring\files\
for %%f in ("\\networkshare1\*.txt") do (
    copy "%%f" "%dest%"
    echo %TIME% >"%dest%%%~nxf:copywhen"
)
```

This copies each manually and appends the time to the [data stream](http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml) `copywhen`, which is permanently associated with the file when its in situ on an NTFS volume.

I'm *pretty* sure Perl's standard file routines will allow reading this back by simply passing the path as `C:\monitoring\files\whatever.txt:copywhen`, if not you can capture the output from the command line `more <"C:\monitoring\files\whatever.txt:copywhen"`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [File::stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) package. This replaces the internal Perl [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) command with a *by name* interface. However, you could use either the builtin `stat` command, or the `File::stat` package.

```
use File::stat;
use feature qw(say);

my $file_stat = stat($file_name);
say "The following times are displayed as seconds since January 1, 1970"
say "    File Last Access time: " . $file_stat->atime;
say "    File Last Modification time: " . $file_stat->mtime;
say "    File inode Change Time: " . $file_stat->ctime;
```

One of these should do it. I think your best bet might be `mtime`.

If you don't want to use `File::Stat` use the builtin `stat` command:

```
say "The following times are displayed as seconds since January 1, 1970"
say "    File Last Access time: " . (stat $my_file)[8]
say "    File Last Modification time: " . (stat $my_file)[9];
say "    File inode Change Time: " . (stat $my_file)[10];
```

To convert the time into something human readable, use the [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to just delete the file right before you copy it. Since it's being copied from another drive, the time/date stamp should be when it was copied to the drive. That's the way windows has always worked for me. ^_^